# Best way to validate entire Json response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know best way to verify entire Json response in Jmeter. Can somebody help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is use [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class like:

1. Put the anticipated JSON into `expected` JMeter Variable using i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) test element like:

   [image: JMeter User Defined Vairables]
2. Add JSR223 Assertion as a child of the request you want to validate
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('expected'))
   def actual = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   if (expected != actual) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual JSON')
   }
   ```
4. If there will be any difference between expected and actual JSON - the sampler will be marked as failed

   [image: JMeter JSR223 Assertion JSON]